# Getting url after a saving file (not using django model)

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, django-storage

I am trying to retrieve the url of a file saved immediately after I have saved it.

Note that I am not using `Django` `model` for the file to be saved. I am saving the file manually using `default_storage.save()`. Obviously with a model it would be easy to retrieve the url.

Currently I have `path = default_storage.save(somefile, ContentFile(upload.file.read()))
)`. I am using AWS Amazon Web Services S3. The files are being saved however I cannot get the url to access the file, I just get back the file name with `path`. How can I get the url?

If it was locally I could have done something like:

```
path = default_storage.save(somefile, ContentFile(upload.file.read()))
full_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, path)
```

to get the url/path. Is there anything like that I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
settings.py

MEDIA_ROOT = URL_BUCKET_S3  #it can be another variable different from MEDIA_ROOT
```

and the `views.py`

```
path = default_storage.save(somefile, ContentFile(upload.file.read()))
full_path = settings.MEDIA_ROOT + path
```

something very similar is how I work in my projects

Comment: What did you set `URL_BUCKET_S3` as? The actual url? How do you get that? or do you have to manually write in the `https://bucket_name....amazonaws.com...etc`?

Comment: Yes. The URL of you bucket s3

Comment: Hey I marked your answer as right, however you need to change `full_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, path)` to `full_path = settings.MEDIA_ROOT + path`. I think the because os.path causes problem. However maybe that was what worked for you.

Comment: You're right, sorry, copy what you had and I did not think about that. the os.path gets you the absolute path and how, in this case, it is a url is not necessary.

I correct my answer, thanks for the observation.

Comment: You can also use this to get the url if you want `default_storage.url(path)`. You can include this in answer as alternative. I did not even know that default storage has a `url` method. It is much cleaner as well.